# Linux ssh user connect

Tags: linux, ssh, users

I all, I have a linux Server (Ubuntu) where some user can be connect to by ssh.
Is possible to know who was connected to the server?
A sort of list of login by ssh of the past day.
Is possible to retrieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`who`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/who) will show you who is currently connected.
[`w`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/w) will show you who is curretly connected, plus what command they're running.
[`last`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/last) will show you all users logged in/out since `/var/log/wtmp` was last rolled.

The contents of `/var/log/auth.log` and/or `/var/log/secure` may also be useful, but the commands above will probably get you what you need to know

Comment: I don't want who is connect in that moment but who connected in last days. I'll see this file

Comment: I don't have /var/log/auth.log /var/log/wtmp and /var/log/secure no files.. :(

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this'll help but I came across the **last** command recently. It shows:

- User name
- Tty device number
- Login date and time
- Logout time
- Total working time

For Example:
[image: Example]

Also, If I'm not mistaken, remote login attempts are stored in the /var/log/secure logs as well.

Hope this Helps..

Comment: I don't have file or folder in var/log/secure. Secure isn't exist

Comment: Can you try the following --> 


grep -ir ssh /var/log/* and grep -ir security /var/log/*

Comment: Nothing return to me